# Change Dynamic URL to "Static" URL

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting

---

> Long story short:

## [THE OPPOSITE OF THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk7Zj.png)

---

---

## What I want

This:

```
domain.com/cpanel?action=new-post
```

to this:

```
domain.com/cpanel/new-post
```

---

## More info

> - I'm using WordPress if it matters anyhow (Probably can't be solved with permalinks any way)
> - `new-post` is an example dynamic page that exists but there can be
>     more than 1 page based on user selection.
>
>   **for example**: `cpanel?action=my-posts`, `cpanel?action=favourites`, etc..
> - Here's what my nginx configuration file contains: http://pastebin.com/QnVu4ef9

---

## Questions

> - How do I remove the `"action?=something"` from the URL?
> - Use **NGINX** to do it or edit `.php` file ?

Comment: Without using .htaccess file.

Comment: in configuration I think you can set rewrite url by php

Comment: Naumov might be mistaken, I think. Or he might be talking about the configuration of WordPress?

Comment: You say you want `THE OPPOSITE OF THIS`, but that's not true, that is what you want.

Comment: I think what the image is saying is: rewrite friendly URL `/cpanel/something/` to query URL  
`/cpanel?action=something` which in that case, i need the opposite

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The image, you link to, shows you an example of what you want.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk7Zj.png

This is how it goes: In the browser you type:

```
http://anysite.com/listings/123
```

This is then rewritten into to:

```
http://anysite.com/listings.html?listing=123
```

by the rewrite rule that is shown. This has the effect that within PHP you have:

```
$listing = $_GET['listing'];
```

available. So for the user it seems like a 'static url', but for PHP it is not.

Extra Info: The controller at **listing.html** is in this case the PHP file I am talking about. The user-friendly URL is typed into the browser and handled by **listing.html**.

Comment: Here's a link to my website: https://www.tilevoas.com/cpanel?action=add-directory to clarify better what I'm looking to achieve. I want the opposite of what I have. So, in order to achieve that, I need to edit my file ( not nginx ) as I understood

Comment: You talk about: 'my file ( not nginx )', what file is that? Which webserver are you using?

Comment: I am using NGINX. I will check right now for which .php file I'm talking about

Comment: See: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite Remeber that the rewrite replaces what goes into your PHP script, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the website url structure then do below steps.

- go to the setting menu tab on the wp admin menu
- go to the setting>> permalink menu item and click on this

then you can see different different type of url structure. seletct you wanted type then click on the save button,

I hope it's work for you..